# Laravel 5: Guzzle not displaying proper restful api responce

Tags: api, rest, laravel, guzzle

Can anyone help me with my problem, i'm trying to use Guzzle in Laravel 5 and trying to retrieve a data from Rest API. i always get this when I dd().

```
Stream {#287 ▼
  -stream: :stream {@11 ▶}
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

and here's my controller, not sure if i'm integrating with guzzle properly.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SampleController extends \SleepingOwl\Admin\Controllers\AdminController {

    public function getIndex() {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
        $body = $response->getBody();
        dd($body);
        //return \View::make('samplerest')->with('tests',$body);
    }
}
```

Comment: got it... turns out I just need to json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `$response->json();` like this :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$json = $response->json();
```

Note that it'll throw an Exception if the response is not well formatted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Doesn't it ? He did ask for a way to retrieve data from his API (understand readable and usable data). My answer allow him to do that in a simple way and a simpler way that he suggests in his comment.

Comment: It's not really a great answer to the question, but an answer none the less... Would you be able to give more detail? maybe a code snippet?

Comment: Somewhat late to the party here but this looks like a pretty perfect answer to the question to me. Yes it could certainly do with a bit of explanation (e.g. why `dd()` makes it look like the response is a `Stream` object but casting to string would give a JSON string, and therefore how to get a JSON object from that by either doing `json_decode` or just using `$response->json()`) but, otherwise, it looks like the exact thing David was looking for.